# Upgrading 2007 master page to 2010

Tags: master-page

My site is on 2010 foundation, but our master page is still the 2007 version.  We'd like to upgrade to the 2010 version in order to get the perks of 2010 (pop-up item editing, ribbon, etc.)  Can someone point me to a good resource on how to do this and how to publish the changes?  I've found a few that say I need to add some placeholders and remove some sections, but i'm not sure in what file to do this in and where to put the new placeholders. 
I have some experience with Sharepoint, but not so much in the master page department :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *strongly* recommend simply creating your 2010 master page from scratch using one of the defined [starter master pages](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/releases/view/41533).  The reason is because certain 2010 UI elements i.e. the Ribbon) are ***very*** fussy and trying to shoehorn them into an existing 2007 master page will only end in pain - a lot of it.  Better to create a new master page that is based on the 2010 structure and simply include the same main ContentPlaceholders that the 2007 one includes.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  I downloaded a starter master page from the link you provided. (Starter 2010 Master Pages by Randy Drisgill.zip)  So, now I have _starter_foundation.master and I'm sure I could import that and apply it to the site.  The question is, what do I need to move over from my existing master page so that it looks the way it does now (aside from the new 2010 functionality)  I could do a diff on the file, but I guess my question is where do I start in terms of moving things (what do I move over and what do I leave out from the 2010 master)  Do I include all the 2007 content place holders?

Comment: I would only include the default placeholder (which should be in the starter master page anyway) and any custom placeholders that you have added. As to whether or not to move the current master page, I would say No because the 07 master would likely need you to run your site as an 07 site instead of a 10 site which could affect other things. The Ribbon really changes the way the page works so it is sometimes better to use the old master page merely as a visual guide and create new Html/CSS for 2010.  This is especially true if your 07 site used a lot of tables or absolute positioning